# Is there a metric space $X$ having either $1012$ , or $1036$ , or $1089$ many open sets?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space , $n$ be the no. of open sets in $X$ , then the possible values of $n$ are :

1) $1012$

2)$1024$

3)$1036$

4)$1089$

I know that $1024$ is a possible value because it is a power of $2$ , so if we endow $X$ with discrete metric we are done . My question is , is any other value from the options possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that in any metric space, all singleton sets are closed, 
e.g. by showing $X \setminus \{p\} = \cup \{B(y,d(p,y)): y \neq p\}$ which is open.

This means that all finite subsets are closed, and if $X$ is itself finite, all finite subsets are open as well (as their complements are finite hence closed). So a finite metric space is discrete. So the number of its open sets is a power of $2$, in particular, if $X$ has $n$ points, there are $2^n$ many subsets, all of which are open.